# Mp android chart, bar chart with bar gradient background

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

dear community, I'm facing the following problem, I'm creating a bar chart using the MP android Chart library available here: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart.

I'd like to set a gradient background for my bars, using the following code I was able to set the gradient background and get the following result.

```
val barDataSet = BarDataSet(dummyYValues, "DataSet 1")
barDataSet.axisDependency = YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT

val startColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.top_graph)
val endColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.bottom_graph)

val gradientColors: MutableList<GradientColor> = ArrayList()
gradientColors.add(GradientColor(endColor, startColor))

barDataSet.gradientColors = gradientColors
dataSets.add(barDataSet)
val finalData = BarData(dataSets)
finalData.barWidth =(0.3f)
```

[image: current result]

And I'm trying to archive something like the following example
[image: Expected behavior]

If you see the main difference is that the expected behavior displaying the gradient color in a uniform way, it means that it displays the color according to the graph not according to the values.

also, if anyone knows how to add the round corner at the top of the bars that would be helpful too.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the best solution but I copied the BarChart renderer class as:

```
public class RoundedBarChartRenderer extends BarLineScatterCandleBubbleRenderer{
    protected void drawDataSet(Canvas c, IBarDataSet dataSet, int index) {

    //Use this to replace the line c.drawRect(.....)
    RectF rectF = new RectF(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
        buffer.buffer[j + 3]);
    c.drawRoundRect(rectF,15f,15f, mRenderPaint);
}}
```

Use the above class like this:

```
chart.renderer = RoundedBarChartRenderer(
    chart,
    chart.animator,
    chart.viewPortHandler
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a gradient background for a bar chart, use the code below.

```
barDataSet.setGradientColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF5722"),Color.parseColor("#FFFF5722");
```

Then use this to curve the corners of the bar chart. I got this from another source and it works perfectly. Here is the code.

```
CustomBarChartRender barChartRender = new CustomBarChartRender(barchart,barchart.getAnimator(), barchart.getViewPortHandler());
barChartRender.setRadius(12);
barchart.setRenderer(barChartRender);
```

create a new class **CustomBarChartRender** and add this,

```
public class CustomBarChartRender extends BarChartRenderer {

    private final RectF mBarShadowRectBuffer = new RectF();

    private int mRadius;

    public CustomBarChartRender(BarDataProvider chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
    }

    public void setRadius(int mRadius) {
        this.mRadius = mRadius;
    }

    protected void drawDataSet(Canvas c, @NotNull IBarDataSet dataSet, int index) {

        Transformer trans = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.getAxisDependency());
        mBarBorderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getBarBorderColor());
        mBarBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(Utils.convertDpToPixel(dataSet.getBarBorderWidth()));
        mShadowPaint.setColor(dataSet.getBarShadowColor());
        boolean drawBorder = dataSet.getBarBorderWidth() > 0f;

        float phaseX = mAnimator.getPhaseX();
        float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();

        if (mChart.isDrawBarShadowEnabled()) {
            mShadowPaint.setColor(dataSet.getBarShadowColor());

            BarData barData = mChart.getBarData();

            float barWidth = barData.getBarWidth();
            float barWidthHalf = barWidth / 2.0f;
            float x;

            int i = 0;
            double count = Math.min(Math.ceil((int) (double) ((float) dataSet.getEntryCount() * phaseX)), dataSet.getEntryCount());
            while (i < count) {

                BarEntry e = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(i);

                x = e.getX();

                mBarShadowRectBuffer.left = x - barWidthHalf;
                mBarShadowRectBuffer.right = x + barWidthHalf;

                trans.rectValueToPixel(mBarShadowRectBuffer);

                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(mBarShadowRectBuffer.right)) {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }

                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(mBarShadowRectBuffer.left))
                    break;

                mBarShadowRectBuffer.top = mViewPortHandler.contentTop();
                mBarShadowRectBuffer.bottom = mViewPortHandler.contentBottom();

                c.drawRoundRect(mBarRect, mRadius, mRadius, mShadowPaint);

                /*if (mRadius > 0)
                    c.drawRoundRect(mBarRect, mRadius, mRadius, mHighlightPaint);
                else
                    c.drawRect(mBarRect, mHighlightPaint);*/

                i++;
            }
        }

        // initialize the buffer
        BarBuffer buffer = mBarBuffers[index];
        buffer.setPhases(phaseX, phaseY);
        buffer.setDataSet(index);
        buffer.setInverted(mChart.isInverted(dataSet.getAxisDependency()));
        buffer.setBarWidth(mChart.getBarData().getBarWidth());

        buffer.feed(dataSet);

        trans.pointValuesToPixel(buffer.buffer);

        boolean isSingleColor = dataSet.getColors().size() == 1;

        if (isSingleColor) {
            mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor());
        }


        int j = 0;
        while (j < buffer.size()) {

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(buffer.buffer[j + 2])) {
                j += 4;
                continue;
            }

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(buffer.buffer[j]))
                break;

            if (!isSingleColor) {
                // Set the color for the currently drawn value. If the index
                // is out of bounds, reuse colors.
                mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor(j / 4));
            }

            if (dataSet.getGradientColor() != null) {
                GradientColor gradientColor = dataSet.getGradientColor();
                mRenderPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(
                        buffer.buffer[j],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 3],
                        buffer.buffer[j],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 1],
                        gradientColor.getStartColor(),
                        gradientColor.getEndColor(),
                        android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
            }

            if (dataSet.getGradientColors() != null) {
                mRenderPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(
                        buffer.buffer[j],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 3],
                        buffer.buffer[j],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 1],
                        dataSet.getGradientColor(j / 4).getStartColor(),
                        dataSet.getGradientColor(j / 4).getEndColor(),
                        Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
            }
            Path path2 = roundRect(new RectF(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                    buffer.buffer[j + 3]), mRadius, mRadius);
            c.drawPath(path2, mRenderPaint);
            if (drawBorder) {
                Path path = roundRect(new RectF(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 3]), mRadius, mRadius);
                c.drawPath(path, mBarBorderPaint);
            }

            j += 4;
        }

    }

    @NotNull
    private Path roundRect(@NotNull RectF rect, float rx, float ry) {
        float top = rect.top;
        float left = rect.left;
        float right = rect.right;
        float bottom = rect.bottom;
        Path path = new Path();
        if (rx < 0) rx = 0;
        if (ry < 0) ry = 0;
        float width = right - left;
        float height = bottom - top;
        if (rx > width / 2) rx = width / 2;
        if (ry > height / 2) ry = height / 2;
        float widthMinusCorners = (width - (2 * rx));
        float heightMinusCorners = (height - (2 * ry));

        path.moveTo(right, top + ry);
        path.rQuadTo(0, -ry, -rx, -ry);//top-right corner
        path.rLineTo(-widthMinusCorners, 0);
        path.rQuadTo(-rx, 0, -rx, ry); //top-left corner
        path.rLineTo(0, heightMinusCorners);

        path.rLineTo(0, ry);
        path.rLineTo(rx, 0);

        path.rLineTo(widthMinusCorners, 0);
        path.rLineTo(rx, 0);
        path.rLineTo(0, -ry);

        path.rLineTo(0, -heightMinusCorners);

        path.close();//Given close, last lineto can be removed.

        return path;
    }}
```